# Proj string issue

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, string

Could anyone explain why the target in this proj string is not correct?

```
$ projinfo -s EPSG:4326 -t '+proj=gnom +lat_0=61.39107201212929 +lon_0=-58.56360634793518' -o PROJ
```

> target CRS string is not a CRS

Comment: Thank you so much Gabriel! I was trying to debug why pyproj was returning all Nan/Infs without producing an error message, and turned to projinfo. And thanks for the edit Vince! I'll reread the policies. I am not a frequent visitor.

Comment: Brendan you are welcome. `Inf` values are common for latitudes `> 90 degrees` or values that are not in the domain of the conversion (like the Northen hemisfere in a South Pole gnomonic projection), don't forget that the axis order for `EPSG:4326` is `(latitude, longitude)`.

Comment: Thanks again Gabriel. I am using shapley and pyproj, and shapely expects x,y order in its transform call. I used the `pyproj.Transformer.from_crs` option `always_xy=True` and my problems were solved! I submitted a ticket to shapely suggesting they update their docs regarding this issue i.e. always use `always_xy=True` with pyproj CRS for shapely. Stay safe in these troubling times!

Answer (score 3):

The string is considered as a coordinate operation in this case. You need to include the `+type=crs` to be considered as a CRS.

From the [Transformations Setup section of the Functions page](https://proj.org/development/reference/functions.html#transformation-setup) of the docs:

> If a proj-string contains a +type=crs option, then it is interpreted as a CRS definition.
>   [...]
>   The use of proj-string to describe a CRS is discouraged. It is a legacy means of conveying CRS descriptions: use of object codes (EPSG:XXXX typically) or WKT description is recommended for better expressivity.
>
> If a proj-string does not contain +type=crs, then it is interpreted as a coordination operation / transformation.

---

In my case:

```
$ projinfo
Rel. 6.2.1, November 1st, 2019
[...]  

$ projinfo -s EPSG:4326 -t '+proj=gnom +lat_0=61.39107201212929 +lon_0=-58.56360634793518 +type=crs' -o PROJ
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation n°1:

unknown id, axis order change (2D) + unknown, 0 m, World

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=gnom +lat_0=61.3910720121293 +lon_0=-58.5636063479352 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84
```

Note that the last step of the returned string does not have the `+type=crs` parameter.